# Repeater in updatepanel not showing rows correctly

Tags: asp.net, .net, updatepanel, repeater

I have a table with 500 rows. Firstly, I have bound the repeater on load to test the output of the table, and the table displays perfectly. But my main aim is to use the repeater in the updatepanel, so once a user clicks show, the updatepanel show display the 500 row table. The table displays, but for some reason some columns randomly are mis-alligned in internet explorer 9. I have tested in firefox and it seems to render fine.

Any ideas?

here are a few snippet codes that i use..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbreakdown" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbreakdown_Click">Show Breakdown</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Repeater ID="tblstatementhistory" runat="server">
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
                <br />
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="tblstatementhistory" style="margin-left: 3px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Worker Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Reference No.
                        </th>
                        <th class="smallcolumn">
                            Method
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Sent On
                        </th>
                        <th class="largecolumn">
                            Delivery Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Container.DataItem("fullname")%>&nbsp;</td><%# vbCrLf%>
                    <td><%# Container.DataItem("xxh")%>&nbsp;</td><%# vbCrLf%>
                    <td><%# getMethod(CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("EMAILID"), enumObjectType.IntType), CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("POSTEDID"), enumObjectType.IntType))%>&nbsp;</td><%# vbCrLf%>
                    <td><%# getStatus(CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("email_ts")), CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("post_ts")))%>&nbsp;</td><%# vbCrLf%>
                    <td><%# getdelivery(CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("status"), enumObjectType.IntType), CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("timestampupdate")), CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("email_ts")), CheckDBNull(Container.DataItem("post_ts")))%>&nbsp;</td><%# vbCrLf%>
                 </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    <ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems to be a rendering/overhead with IE when running a postback. I now have changed my method from using asp.net updatepanel to use jquery with JSON. This retrieves my data now, and does not have any misalligned rows/columns.